# How to pass multiple options id in angular

Tags: angular, api, rxjs, angular-material, crud

I'm trying to pass multiple select options with an array reactive forms, here is my code
HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="teamForm"  (ngSubmit)="saveTeam(teamForm)" novalidate>
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-select  formControlName="tblUsers"  name="tblUsers" multiple>
              <mat-option>Select Users</mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options let i =index"  [value]="option.id">{{option.name}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
<button>Ok</button>
</form>
```

Comment: A mat-select multiple return an array, so your control "tblUsers" is a **FormControl** that store an array, **not** a FormArray. Yes, a FormControl can store an array (or a Date or a complex object, not only a number or a string). NOTE: To give an initial value to the formControl you need "feed" with an array, e.g. `this.teamForm.get('tblUsers').setValue([1,5,6])` or `this.teamForm=new FormGroup({tblUsers:new FormControl([1,5,6])}`

Comment: so the main problem is that i'm keeping my tblUsers formControl empty

Comment: I think that you can use `null` but sure not `''`